# Remote Debugging HTTP requests using Go and GoLand IDE

Tags: docker, go, jetbrains-ide, delve, goland

I am new to go, delve and GoLand IDE. I would like to remote debug some REST endpoints that are deployed using `make` and run in a docker (using docker + docker-compose).

The command I use to bring up my environment is `make myproject`

My endpoints get hosted at: `localhost:8080`

When creating a debug configuration in GoLand it specifies that before running
`dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version 2`, do the following:

```
go build -gcflags='-N -l' github.com/myproject
dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api version=2 exec ./myproject
```

Is there a way for me to attach to my project once it's running on localhost:8080? How will these commands differ if that is the case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command `dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version 2 your/package/name` allows delve to compile the package then launch itself and the compiled binary.

On the other hand, these commands

`go build -gcflags='-N -l' github.com/myproject
dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api version=2 exec ./myproject`

show you that you can compile the binary separately, in case you need more flexibility and then launch the debugger. Keep in mind that it's really important to add `-gcflags='-N -l'` or `-gcflags='all=-N -l'`, depending on which Go version you have, in order for the debugger to be able to have more data available about your application.

As for the:

> Is there a way for me to attach to my project once it's running on localhost:8080? How will these commands differ if that is the case?

It depends on where you are running the process. If it's on your machine directly, without a VM or a container, then the IDE has the option in `Run|Attach to Process`. If the process is running on a different machine then you need to login into that machine and use `dlv --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version 2 attach <pid>`.

We published [an article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/) dedicated to this problem a couple of months ago, please have a look at it for a more detailed reply.